# C++ console output affects chrono::steady_clock time measurements

Tags: c++, time, g++, cout, c++-chrono

I need to measure the average execution time of an operation, to do that I run the operation inside a loop like so:

```
double sum = 0;
int count = 100;
for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
  Timer t;

  t.startTimer();
  someOperation();
  t.endTimer();

  sum += t.getTimeInNanoseconds();
}
```

And then I divide sum by count to obtain the average time.
However for some odd reason, if I were to output something to the console inside the loop BUT outside the t.startTimer() and t.endTimer() calls, the execution times rise.

The problem appears when running the code on a virtual machine as well as on a regular computer.

What's causing this?

Here's how the Timer class looks like:

```
class Timer {
  std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock> startTime, endTime;

  void startTimer() {
    startTime = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
  }

  void endTimer() {
    endTime = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
  }

  double getTimeInNanoseconds() {
    return (endTime - startTime).count();
  }
}
```

I've tried using high_resolution_clock before but with similar results.

EDIT - MVCE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

class Timer {
public:
  std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock> startTime, endTime;

  void startTimer() {
    startTime = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
  }

    void endTimer() {
    endTime = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
  }

    double getTimeInNanoseconds() {
    return (endTime - startTime).count();
  }
};

void foo() {
  int a;
  for(int n = 0 ; n < 10000000; n++) {
    a += 1;
  }
}

int main() {

  double sum1 = 0;
  int count = 100;
  for(int i =0; i < count; i++) {
    Timer t;

    t.startTimer();
    foo();
    t.endTimer();

    sum1 += t.getTimeInNanoseconds() / 1000000;
  }



  double sum2 = 0;
  for(int i =0; i < count; i++) {
    Timer t;

    t.startTimer();
    foo();
    t.endTimer();

    cout << "Foo" << endl;
    cout << "Bar" << endl;
    cout << "Foo" << endl;

    sum2 += t.getTimeInNanoseconds() / 1000000;
  }

  cout << "Average time 1: " << sum1 / (double) count << endl;
  cout << "Average time 2: " << sum2 / count << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Now here the time difference isn't as high, but it's still visible, as the sum2 is always larger than sum1.

Comment: First of all, nothing guarantees you that difference between two time_points of steady_clock will be nanoseconds. But that just semantical issue with your code. To address the actual problem, I need to see the MCVE - what has been measured, what is being output, etc. There can be multitude of reasons.

Comment: It's a university assingment, I'm measuring how long it takes to convert a number from a residue number system format to an 128 bit number. And the problem is that no matter what I output, the execution times rise.

Comment: You need to post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Can't the CPU reorder instructions and potentially move the output wherever it likes?  Or does the chronological have fences to prevent that?

Comment: My guess would be that because you are performing those calls to non-trivial output routines, you've cleared some registers used by the time-sensitive part of the loop.  Those registers will need to be reloaded, and the compiler has put those extra instructions between the timer calls.  You could verify this theory by looking at a disassembly of your code.

Comment: Your MCVE is moot. The compiler will simply not generate any code for your foo(), so what you are measuring will be simply 0.

Comment: Just in case it helps: in such situations it's sometimes practical to collect the outputs of interest in a pre-allocated array, and wait until all timing is finished before converting them to ASCII and outputting them....